# How can i convert this match statement into a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

How could I convert this `match` block into a HashMap? Ideally I would like to create a HashMap from a manifest file:

```
match layers[1][p] {
    ',' => tile = grass,
    '*' => tile = sand,

    // And so on....
}
```

I tried doing this earlier, but Macroquad's Texture2D is not compatible with a HashMap. (I think the compiler said 'Cannot use Option as Texture2D'.)

I would like to do something like this:

```
let tile = hashmap.get(layers[p]);
blit(tile);
```

Comment: So you want to say `hashmap.get('*')` and get `sand`?

Comment: Sort of, i was going to do hashmap.get(layers[p]) to replace having to match layers[p]. I am a novice at programming BTW.

Comment: FYI the variable 'p' checks an external file that has been cached and reads the chars from the data.

Comment: OK, i edited the question, look at the bottom of the question, and u will see what i desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's keep this simple. I don't think hashmap will simplify anything but why not demonstrate it. The true advantage of hash is that you can load tiles dynamically and make them loaded into the map. For now, though, we will hardcode some.

```rust
fn main() {
    
    /* snip */
    let mut textures = HashMap::new();
    textures.insert(',', grass);
    textures.insert('*', sand);

    /* snip */
    
    // mind that your program will crash if map does 
    // not contain the texture
    let texture = textures.get(layers[p]).unwrap();
    blit(texture)
}
```